# we need to write a prorgam that asks a user to enter multiple numbers and ends the while loop with -1.then work out the average of numbers provided

Tags: python, input, while-loop

we have been tasked with writing a program in python asking a user to enter multiple numbers.
the subject is while loops,so we can only make use of while loops and if statements.
when the user wants to stop the entry of numbers,the user then needs to type '-1'.
once that has been done,the program must return the average of the numbers entered by the user.

this is what i have so far:
#task 13-while.py

```
 #first the program will explain to the user that the user can keep
#entering numbers until -1 occurs.



  num = int(input('''please enter any number of your choice\n
  please enter -1 to stop entry and run program'''))

num_count = 0
while num > -1:
num_count = num_count + 1
average = sum(num)/num_count

if num == -1:
print("the average of the numbers you have entered is"+ average)
```

extremely inexperienced with python,all help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the input into the while and then only when the loop is over calculate the average
Like this:

```
num = int(input("enter numbers and then -1 to stop: "))
num_count = 1
sum = num
while num!=-1:
    num = int(input("another number: "))
    num_count+=1
    sum+=num
print(sum/num_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for it to work you need to add an `input()` call inside the `while` loop like in the code bellow :

```
count = 0
sum = 0
num = int(input('''please enter any number of your choice\n
please enter -1 to stop entry and run program\n'''))

while num != -1:
    sum += num
    count +=1
    num = int(input('''Give another integer\n'''))


print("the average of the numbers you have entered is", sum/count)
```

**Personal advice :** I would suggest for you to read more tutorials or ask your peofessor for more work